# Get data from single cell in laravel by querying

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.3

## Json data

```
[  
   {  
      "id":2,
      "firstname":"abc",
      "lastname":"def",
      "email":"abc@some.ac.uk",
      "role":1,
      "university":1,
      "school_dept":5,
      "year":2,
      "photo":"URL",
      "bio":"ObxBJIDO6IfOU0DIw8a5",
      "search_status":"available",
      "created_at":null,
      "updated_at":null,
      "languages":[  
         {  
            "id":3,
            "language":"Spanish",
            "pivot":{  
               "user_id":2,
               "language_id":3,
               "type":"native"
            }
         },
         {  
            "id":4,
            "language":"Greek",
            "pivot":{  
               "user_id":2,
               "language_id":4,
               "type":"learn"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

I would like to get the language_id of the loggedin user.
if user logged in as id = 2(auth::user()->id).

Then for above data I would like to receive output as:

```
$learn = 4(language_id)

$native= 3(language_id)
```

I tried to do it like:

```
$learn = User::with('languages')->where([['languages.pivot.user_id',Auth::user()->id],['languages.pivot.type','learn']])

$teach = User::with('languages')->where([['languages.pivot.user_id',Auth::user()->id],['languages.pivot.type','native']])
```

the relationship between user and languages is many to many with extra field called type(native or learn) as pivot.

## Table format for User, Language_User, Language

```
User_table
id
name
....

Language_User
id
user_id
language_id
type('learn','native')

Language_table
id
language
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do what you're after is to constrain the relationship e.g.:

```
$learn = User::with(['languages' => function (Builder $q) {
    $q->wherePivot('type', 'learn');
}])->where('id', Auth::user()->id);
```

If it's for the authenticated user you could just do:

```
$learn = Auth::user()->languages()->wherePivot('type', 'learn')->get();
```

Or if you could even define it as a relationship:

```
public function languagesToLearn()
{
   return $this->languages()->wherePivot('type', 'learn');
}
```

Then you could do:

```
$learn = User::with('languagesToLearn')->where('id', Auth::user()->id);
```

or

```
$learn = Auth::user()->languagesToLearn;
```

If you want to just get the languages you could then do:

```
Auth::user()->languagesToLearn()->pluck('language')
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#aggregates

Hope this helps!

Comment: I want a single value name of the language but I get this: [{"id":3,"language":"Spanish","pivot":{"user_id":10,"language_id":3,"type":"learn"}}] from above query. Also, one with function builder gives error: Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder could not be converted to string

Comment: @MurlidharFichadia I think the error was being caused by having two `wherePivot()` (my bad). I've added to my answer.